# fprintln() writting Linux-style end of line under Windows

Tags: go

I'm running Go on Windows and writing lines to a file with `fmt.Fprintln(w, line)`, but the end of line is Linux style end of lines and not Windows. Is there an environment variable I need to set or something?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493867/what-is-the-most-portable-cross-platform-way-to-represent-a-newline-in-go-golang

Answer (score 1):

No, fmt always uses unix line endings. If you want something different, you need to print it yourself.

Comment: Relevant code section: [pkg/fmt/print.go](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/fmt/print.go?name=go1.1.2#1146).

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen Weinberg already said, the print function in `fmt` always use `\n` as line
separator.

You can see this in the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/fmt/print.go?name=go1.1.2#1146).

As a workaround you may define your own print function or use `Printf` instead of `Println`:

```
fmt.Printf("Foo\r\n")
```

If you want to define a global string for the newline used in the environment your program runs,
you may create a `.go` file for each operating system and use build tags to select the right one.

Alternatively, write a function which parses `runtime.GOOS` ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/KRKZfdbNGt)):

```
func Newline() string {
    switch runtime.GOOS {
    case "windows":
        return "\r\n"
    // ...more...
    case "linux":
        fallthrough
    default:
        return "\n"
    }
}

fmt.Printf("This is a line%s", Newline())
```